# TypeError: e.handler.apply is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little jQuery error. I have searched and read the others topics about it, and tried the solutions, but it didn't work.

Here is my code :

```
function paf() {
    // My function - It is working, so I guess the problem is not there. 
}

jQuery(document).ready(paf)
jQuery(window).load(jQuery('input').bind('keyup', paf())) // The problem is here
```

The last line has to update the price when the user type on a input box, but it gives the error :

> TypeError: e.handler.apply is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you don't have to have `()` and `.load()` should have an anonymous function:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){ // load takes a function as param.
    jQuery('input').bind('keyup', paf); // <---remove () from paf
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are passing a jQuery object as the load callback value.

You can call the `paf` and have the event registration code in the dom ready callback itself like

```
function paf() {
  // My function - It is working, so I guess the problem is not there. 
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  paf();
  jQuery('input').on('keyup', paf)
})
```